# Proper way to update texture (THREE.JS)

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I have some checkbox booleans that load different textures to a sphere in three.js.

I am running into the issue of these images not loading fast enough, causing some drag on performance. I imagine I will need to preload them but not sure the best way for that. I am also including my current code as there may be a better solution altogether or some unneeded code of mine.

```
function showPoliticalMap(){
    var world = scene.getObjectByName("world").children[1],
        cloud = scene.getObjectByName("cloud"),
        uri = world.material.map.image.baseURI;

    scene.remove(cloud);
    spotlight.intensity = 0;
    ambientLight.intensity = 1;
    world.material.map.image.currentSrc = uri + "img/earthmapoutlineblue_optimized.jpg";
    world.material.map.image.src = uri + "img/earthmapoutlineblue_optimized.jpg";
    world.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
    world.material.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove clouds and change light intensity after the texture has been changed, then you need to load the texture before. You can use the `TextureLoader` for this, check the [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader). In the example below you dont really need the download progress callback, but the error callback could be good to keep.

```
function showPoliticalMap(){
    var world = scene.getObjectByName("world").children[1],
        cloud = scene.getObjectByName("cloud"),
        uri = world.material.map.image.baseURI;

    // instantiate a loader
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    // load a resource
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        uri + "img/earthmapoutlineblue_optimized.jpg",
        // Function when resource is loaded
        function ( texture ) {
            // do something with the texture
            world.material.map = texture;
            world.material.needsUpdate = true;

            scene.remove(cloud);
            spotlight.intensity = 0;
            ambientLight.intensity = 1;
        },
        // Function called when download progresses
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        // Function called when download errors
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( 'An error happened' );
        }
    );
}
```

I haven't tested it so not sure if it will work directly, but it shows the principle of it anyway.

Comment: Ah these indeed does work. I wasn't sure if this was the proper way to update textures but now I know! Thank you. By the way the texture  loader callbacks are bugged/dont work unfortunately. See this issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7734